# Can we use the algebraic definition of group cohomology for $H(BG, A)$ for compact Lie groups $G$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology, classifying-spaces, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

For any discrete group $G$, the classifying space $BG$ is a $K(G, 1)$ and can be constructed as a simplicial set with $|G|^i$ $i$-simplices. Accordingly, elements of $H^i(BG, A)$ can be represented by simplicial $A$-valued $i$-cocycles, which are functions
$$\omega: G^i\rightarrow A\;,$$
which leads to the algebraic definition of group cohomology.

**Question**: To which extent is it possible to apply the algebraic definition of group cohomology to continuous topological groups, such as $SO(3)$ or $U(2)$?

I believe the algebraic definition works at least for $G=U(1)=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. E.g., the generating element of $H(BU(1), \mathbb{Z})$ can be represented via the Bockstein homomorphism for the group extension
$$\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\;,$$
yielding a function
$$\omega(a, b)=\widetilde{a}+\widetilde{b}-\widetilde{ab}\;,$$
with $a, b\in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, $\widetilde \cdot$ being some embedding of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ into $\mathbb{R}$.

Is this also possible for other compact Lie groups and cohomology classes? If yes, what do the explicit cocycles looks like for some common examples, e.g., the first Chern class $c_1\in H^2(BU(2), \mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72810/the-relationship-between-group-cohomology-and-topological-cohomology-theories/74960#74960

Comment: @AndresMejia Thanks! I had seen this question some time ago but forgot. I can't really extract the answer to my question though. I'm interested in the cohomology of $BG$ for the usual topology of the Lie group $G$. I think the cohomology of arbitrary functions $G^i\rightarrow A$ is the cohomology of $BG$ for $G$ with discrete topology, which is not what I want. The cohomology of continuous functions $G^i\rightarrow A$ is not what i want either, since then for discrete $A$ all cocycles would be constant.